# What does "a curious mix of a man" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

Context

*The top-secret American operation to build and use the atom bomb would challenge the humanitarian values on which democracy is built. It was led by one of the most intriguing minds of the 20th century. **J Robert Oppenheimer was a curious mix of a man**. He was fascinated by other cultures and the religions of the east, and, in politics, a man of the left. In fact, he even flirted with communism before the war, and so you might think a strange choice to head a project like this. But he was a brilliant theoretical physicist and a charismatic leader.*

Source: History of the world by Andrew Marr - Episode 8.

Answer (score 1):

It's a way of saying, *a unique man.*

Definition of *curious*:

> Strange; unusual.

Example:

> A *curious* sensation overwhelmed her.

So, based on the description that follows it, your example sentence means,

> J Robert Oppenheimer holds an unusual collection of views.

([Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/curious))